# POSTing files to a PHP API

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, restful-url

I am writing a PHP app with Laravel 5. It manages medical images it will have a RESTful API for getting info on stored files and storing new images.

I have a lot of the GET API commands working and am able to upload image files through an HTML form but I would like to be able to upload file(s) via the API. Could somebody please help with an example of how to pass a file this way rather than with an HTML form? For instance, something like this:

myapp.com/file/upload?file=myfile.dcm

Just a pointer in the right direction would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The html form is creating a POST request for the server, for your upload.php.

This is how your POST looks like:

```
        [name] => 
        [type] => 
        [tmp_name] => 
        [error] => 
        [size] =>
```

You can build this post manually too. Check the reference:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php